# Can you pick out a piece from an input that can vary in size in the middle of the string?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently making a simple discord bot where you can get a random number when typing /roll number, with the number you type being the max. But I also want to be able to type for example /roll 11-17 and get a number between 11 and 17. This is what I've got so far but it can only have single digit numbers as the first ones (/roll 5-15 will get you a number between 5 and 15) :

```
meco = message.content

  if meco.startswith("/roll "):
    if meco[7] == "-":
      minnum = int(meco[6])
      maxnum = int(meco[8:])
      result = random.randint(minnum, maxnum)
      await message.channel.send(result)
    maxnum = int(meco[6:])
    result = (random.randint(1, maxnum))
    await message.channel.send(result)
```

Comment: I suggest a different approach: first `start, end = [int(x) for x in message.split()[1].split('-')]` where `message` is the thing You receive from the user (I guess it would be `meco` for You or sth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if meco.startswith("/roll "):
    if "-" in meco:
        bounds = [int(x) for x in meco.split(" ")[1].split("-")][:2]
        result = random.randint(*bounds)
        await message.channel.send(result)
    else:
        maxnum = int(meco.split(" ")[1])
        result = (random.randint(1, maxnum))
        await message.channel.send(result)
```

You can use `if "-" in meco` to check if the message contents contain a "-" regardless of length. Then you can use `.split(" ")` to split the command into the "/roll" part and the number/range part. Because we want the number/range part, we use `.split(" ")[1]`. Then we split that at the "-" using `.split("-")`. I've then put this inside a list comprehension to convert both strings to integers and used `[:2]` to get the first 2 items, in case the user puts more than one "-" in their message. These can then be used to generate a random integer. `*bounds` takes all the items in the list `bounds` and passes them as parameters to `random.randint`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that `meco` is set to `/roll 5-15`:

1. To handle the `meco` variable, we can first remove the '/roll ' -  `meco = meco[6:]`. This sets `meco` to be '5-15'
2. Check if `meco` contains a '-' character: `if '-' in meco:`
3. If it does contain a '-' then get the minimum and maximum: `minimum, maximum = meco.split('-')`
4. From here you can generate the random number: `result = random.randint(int(minimum), int(maximum))`

**Be aware that your bot will crash if malformed input is not checked for**